# about "so … as to"

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

I think the following sentences have similar meanings.

> He is intelligent enough to solve this question.

> He is so intelligent as to solve this question.

On the other hand, do the following sentences have similar meanings? (In the first place, are the second and third sentences grammatically correct?)

> This question is easy enough for children to solve.

> This question is so easy for children as to solve.

> This question is so easy as for children to solve.

Answer (score 2):

There is the expression "so as to", which implies *intention*. For example, "he posted the question online *so as to* learn the answer". That wouldn't make sense with your examples because they aren't about doing something with an intention.

Sentences constructed like yours, using "so [x] as to [y]" connect a *result* with a *cause*. For example, "the storm was *so* strong *as to* cause damage". This does not fit your examples either, as they are not showing a result and a cause.

> He is intelligent enough to solve this question.

This means that 'he' has *sufficient* intelligence to solve the equation - it doesn't mean that he will solve it, or that he even intends to try.

> This question is easy enough for children to solve.

This means that the question *could* be solved by children, not that they have or they will.

Comment: Then, is this sentence correct? ”He **was** so intelligent as to solve this question.” That he was intelligent is a cause and that he solved this question is a result.

Comment: I can't understand your answer. In ”He **is** so intelligent as to solve this question.”, that he is intelligent is a cause and that he solves this question is a result.

Comment: @Aya That doesn't make sense... how do you *cause* intelligence?

Comment: I said intelligence is a **cause**, not a result. I mean intelligence causes him to solve this question.

Comment: For example, the following sentence is correct, isn't it? ”She was so kind as to show me the way to the station.”

Comment: @aya No, his intelligence *allows* him to solve it. He doesn't have to solve it. Just like I didn't have to answer this question, even though I instinctively know the answer as a native British English. There is a clear difference between ability and cause. Even without thinking about it (which I have, in order to construct you an answer), as a native British English speaker your examples sound wrong. We wouldn't use the construction "so as... to" like this. It doesn't fit the context.

Comment: @aya 'cause and effect' is something that happens, and then something else that happens as a direct consequence of the first. Saying someone has the ability to do something doesn't imply any activity at all.